# Chinese Remainder Theorem with form I have not seen

Tags: discrete-mathematics, chinese-remainder-theorem

One of my professors gave out a practice exam for a Discrete Mathematics test, and I'm having a little trouble with this problem:

"Use the Chinese Remainder's Theorem to find ALL solutions to the system of congruence:

xmod 17 = 5

xmod12 = 3"

I've only ever seen Chinese Remainder Theorem questions set up as:

"x = amod(m1)

x = bmod(m2)
"

So I'm a little confused on how to solve the question in the way he gave it. ie:

"xmod(m1) = a

xmod(m2) = b"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's exactly the same thing as before. you want $x\equiv 5 \bmod 17$ and $x\equiv 3 \bmod 12$

Comment: Usually in mathematics we use equivalence mod $m$ as a relation: $x \equiv b \mod m$.  This prof is using mod $m$ as an operator: $x \mod m = b$.  He may be a computer scientist in disguise...  But yes, it amounts to the same thing.